# Aussprache von Allianz

Tags: pronunciation

Ich habe gesehen, dass die IPA-Aussprache des Worts „Allianz“ aˈli̯anʦ ist, aber der Akzent des Wortes liegt in der zweiten Silbe (also ali̯'anʦ), wie ich es gehört habe.

Warum wird die Aussprache so geschrieben, wenn es wie ali̯'anʦ ausgesprochen wird? Habe ich es schlecht gehört oder hat das Wort eigentlich nur zwei Silben?

Comment: Ich spreche das *Al janz* aus. Für mich sind es tatsächlich nur zwei Silben.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beim schnelleren Sprechen oder zur Ausspracheerleichterung wird aus dreisilbigem [a.li.'ants] zweisilbiges [al.'jants]. Ähnlich auch bei *Filiale*,  *Milliarde*.

Comment: Beim schnellen Aussprechen wird aus dem viersilbigen *Entschuldigung* bekanntermaßen auch das zweisilbige *Tschulljung*.

Comment: Oder *Zarette* für *Zigarette*. <g>

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Bei uns heisst das "Zigrette" :)

Comment: Bei mir sind auch bei langsamem Sprechen (inklusive betont langsam) und im "Silbenklatsch-Modell" Filiale und Milliarde 3-silbig.

Answer (score 2):

Die Aussprache ist [aˈli̯ant͡s].

Das Apostroph zwischen a und l bedeutet: Die nächste Silbe trägt die Hauptbetonung.

In allen Sprachen besteht eine Silbe aus einem Silbenkern (Synonym: »Silbengipfel«), der durch einen einzelnen Vokal, einen Diphthong (zwei verschliffene Vokale) oder seltener auch durch einen sonoren Konsonanten (*m, n, ng, l, r*) gebildet wird, und die umgebenden Konsonanten gehören dann vereinfacht gesagt zu der Silbe, zu deren Silbenkern sie den kleinsten Abstand haben.

Das l zwischen a und i kann kein Silbengipfel sein, weil es in unmittelbarer Nachbarschaft eines Vokals steht. Im Fall dieses l ist hier in diesem Wort nicht ganz klar, ob es mit dem davor stehenden a eine Silbe bildet, oder ob es zum nachfolgenden i gehören soll, wodurch dann das erste a allein eine Silbe bilden würde. Diesen Zustand findet man sehr oft, man nennt einen solchen Konsonanten, der genau auf der Grenze von zwei Silben steht, ein Silbenknie. Dieses l ist so ein Silbenknie.

Von den Konsonanten nach dem zweiten a (n, t, s) kann auch keiner ein Silbengipfel sein. Die Laute [t] und [s] (die hier verschmolzen sind, was durch den Bogen darüber angezeigt wird), sind keine sonoren Konsonanten und kommen prinzipiell nicht als Silbengipfel in Frage. Das [n] kann in Ausnahmefällen diese Rolle einnehmen, dazu küsste es aber zwischen zwei nicht-sonoren Konsonanten stehen. Es steht aber hinter einem Vokal.

Damit ist klar, dass die Laute [ant͡s] zu nur einer Silbe gehören. Anders gesagt: Zwischen diesen Lauten liegt keine Silbengrenze.

Was bleibt ist die Frage, ob das [i] und das darauf folgende [a] zur selben Silbe oder zu zwei verschiedenen Silben gehören. Denkbar wären ja diese beiden Aussprachen (vereinfachte Schreibweise):

> Al-janz
>   A-li-anz

In der Lautschrift des Wortes ([aˈli̯ant͡s]) sieht man aber, das unter dem i noch ein kleiner Bogen steht. Was dieses Zeichen bedeutet, kann man hier nachlesen: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_IPA-Zeichen#Diakritika_und_Suprasegmentalia

Man findet dieses Zeichen im Abschnitt *Diakritika und Suprasegmentalia* im unteren Drittel der Liste, und dort steht:

> ̯ Kennzeichnung eines Lauts, meist eines Vokals, der nicht den Silbenkern bildet.

Man verwendet dieses Zeichen oft bei Diphthongen, also dann, wenn zwei Vokale gemeinsam einen Silbenkern bilden. Dann ist nämlich nur einer der beiden Vokale der "echte" Silbenkern (meist mit Betonung), der meist auch länger klingt, während der andere Vokal nur eine zweitrangige Funktion hat. Und genau das ist hier der Fall.

Bei den meisten Deutschen Diphthongen liegt die Betonung auf dem ersten der beiden Vokale (*Maus, Reis, neu, pfui*). Im Fall des Wortes *Allianz* (das ja auch kein deutsches Wort ist) ist das aber umgekehrt. Im Diphthong *ia* ist das a betont, und das i lehnt sich schwach und müde vorne an das starke a an.

Daher gehört auch das i zur selben Silbe, zu der auch das darauffolgende a gehört. Somit gehört die Lautfolge [i̯ant͡s] zu einer einzigen Silbe. Ob nun das l auch dazu gehört, ist Auffassungssache (siehe oben, Stichwort »Silbenknie«)

In vereinfachter Schreibweise kann man also diese beiden Extremformen ausmachen:

> A-ljanz
>   Al-janz

Die tatsächliche Aussprache liegt in der Mitte dieser beiden Extreme.